# How can I remove and add back a div when an input is selected and also add it back if selection changes

Tags: javascript, html, remove-if

So I am a month into learning JS and I am building a website project that calculates the delivery cost based on the type of parcel and dimensions of the parcel
I have put the dimensions input field (length width and height) in a div (dimensions)
In the event that the parcel is either "cash" or "envelope", I would want to have the dimensions div removed as such details would not be necessary. This is my code.

```
    <select name="" id="typeOfParcel" class="form-control" onchange="assign(),removeDimensions()">
                                <option selected disabled>Select type of Parcel</option>
                                <option value="document" class="form-input form-control form-group">Document</option>
                                <option value="box" class="form-input form-control form-group">Box</option>
                                <option value="envelope" class="form-input form-control form-group">Envelope</option>
                                <option value="Cash" class="form-input form-control form-group">Cash</option>
                                <option value="Groceries" class="form-input form-control form-group">Groceries</option>
                                <option value="Other" class="form-input form-control form-group">Other</option>
                            </select>
                            <p class="text-centre">Dimensions and Weight of the Parcel</p>
                            <div class=" container form-group row p-1" id="dimensions">
                                <div class="col"><label for="length">Length (cm)</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="dimensions" id="length" class="form-control" required
                                        placeholder="cm" min="0" max="160">
                                </div>
    
                                <div class="col"><label for="width">Width (cm)</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="dimensions" id="width" class="form-control" required
                                        placeholder="cm" min="0" max="160">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col"><label for="height">Height (cm)</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="dimensions" id="height" class="form-control" required
                                        placeholder="cm" min="0" max="120">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col"><label for="weight">Weight (kgs)</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" class="form-control" required
                                        placeholder="kg" min="0" max="100">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

JS

```
    function removeDimensions() {
        dimensions=document.getElementById("dimensions").innerHTML;
        if (typeOfParcel==("envelope"||"cash")){
            dimensions=document.getElementById("dimensions").innerHTML;
            dimensions.parentNode.removeChild(dimensions);
    }
```

I have also tried dimensions.remove() and stil get this error in the console:caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined
at removeDimensions.
Any ideas o how I can achieve this

Comment: remove-if is a lisp tag.  `typeOfParcel==("envelope"||"cash")` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I did test the if statement using some simple code and it worked. i.e 
```
if (typeOfParcel==("envelope"||"cash")){
document.getElementByID("deliverySlot").innerHTML="remove dimensions"
    }
```
ANd it it did show "remove dimensions"

Comment: `("envelope"||"cash")` will always evaluate to "envelope" since it's truthy (a non-empty string).  As such, `typeOfParcel==("envelope"||"cash")` is the equivalent to `typeOfParcel=="envelope"`.  It's different from `(typeOfParcel=="envelope"|| typeOfParcel=="cash")`.  FWIW, you'll be more likely to get an answer if you make your code snippet runnable.  As it stands, someone willing to help would need to make a runnable piece of code on their own, and make some assumptions about the missing parts (e.g. the `assign` function, where the `typeOfParcel` variable is assigned, etc.).